# If I edit an old closed question, is it reevaluated? Undeer which circumstances and how often are they reevaluated?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

This question of mine was closed by a moderator for a long time (asked 10 months ago, closed 3 months ago):
[MySQL function to convert a text field encoded with Latin1 to UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457636)

This is another question of mine was closed for a similar reason (3 months ago): [How to change the default font of the form controls in Visual Studio IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636268/how-to-change-the-default-font-of-the-form-controls-in-visual-studio-ide)

They both have accepted answers. I modified them several times with the aim to keep them for future readers. but they still are closed. I thought maybe there is a deadline for editing an old question or a limit on the revisions, and they may never be reopened, no matter how much I improve them.

For the latter question I had actually downloaded a project from the web where the default font of controls was "MS Outlook". I didn't know why it happened and wanted to set it back to "MS Sans serif".

The question was closed as "the problem cannot be reproduced". But the question could be simply stated as "How can I change the default font of the controls of a form in Visual Studio? [this time 'MS Sans serif' to 'MS Outlook']".

**If a question can be restated so it turns to a useful question, then I expect the reason for closing to be reconsidered too.**

If you note to the date of questions, they were asked several months ago. For example the later question was closed 3 months ago, and for the last month it was in its current status, until today it was reopened.

I've heard that when a question got closed, there is little chance for it to be reopened. If that is the case, less motivation remains for me to improve it.

I thought maybe the huge amount of closed questions or a consensus on the moderation side that closed question are mostly unsalvageable cause they pay less attention to the closed questions, specially those which are old.

My aim is just to make them good for future readers. But I am not sure that the community also wants that! I spent some time to polish the question just with the aim to benefit SO, but they deleted it as I mentioned it here, and that wasn't what I expected. It could be just a misunderstanding but in general I feel the old closed questions receive less attention than what the asker may expect.

Under which circumstances they may reevaluate them? How often are they reevaluated? is there any deadline or revision limit?

Comment: It seems one deleted the question I addressed, I think they took this post personally. I still believe that was a good question for future readers. I didn't loose anything, I had found the solution for it, but a good question was removed from SO. My effort was just in the direction to keep this question for people who have similar problem!

Comment: I've restored the question for purposes of letting people see it in re. this post.

Comment: Huuuuuuuuge tip: In the question, it would be super helpful to you if you post the code/queries that you were working with. This gives potential answerers something to work off of. Otherwise, how do they know what you aren't doing right?

Comment: I suggested an edit on your answer, by the way, to improve the grammar a bit. Feel free to reject if you disagree with it.

Comment: @Kendra I can bring examples of thousands of questions here without any code, and with thousands of up votes. sometimes when the question is general bringing code is redundant. if you note the answer the code was what I asked for.

Comment: @Ahmad I see this. What I'm saying is it would improve the question to add code you've tried. Yes, it makes the question a little less general, but you're less likely to get it closed. Honestly, I think if Andrew hadn't closed it as "Debugging help" (if you read the close message, it even says you should really supply the code) "Too Broad" would likely fit as well, as I'm sure there are a number of ways to do what you're asking in your question.

Comment: ["Reopening is hard..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229753/165773)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Please reconsider the question, I really got out of idea what is wrong with it. Please don't take these personally, I just thought it could benefit other users, would like to know why not.

Comment: Down votes just tell me, NO it isn't worth, I'd better back to my work!

Comment: @Ahmad Specifically *because* you brought it up here, I am not taking unilateral action on that post at all except to un-delete it, to give others a chance to reopen if they think it should be. For the record, I do *not* think it should be reopened.

Comment: @Kendra I even modified it to make it similar with the one you may expected, while made it more concise. But it seems as I exposed it here people tend more to vote it down than to vote it up! It had originally one up vote.

Comment: The two questions are apparently different, the other one is about down-votes to the answers of a closed question, but I have asked about why they less are reevaluated? it's probable that there is a time or revisions limit or something ....

Answer (score 9):

What you're observing is simply that there are good and bad ways to phrase a question. If your question is phrased in a way that makes it seem off-topic, it is likely to get closed. If you know what the end goal you want is, you're much better off asking "How can I do [...]" than asking "[...]happened, I don't know why, how can I undo it?". If you do a good job of figuring out how to phrase it in a way which is clear and comes across as on-topic, you're more likely to get an answer. That's really all there is to it.

Comment: But now they deleted it. the question is not mine, I found the solution for it. I just liked to keep it for future readers, if some don't want I don't bother too, By its topic you can say that it was a useful question, but what I see here is that some people think if they delete it they have proved their standing. I don't intend to fight. its now up to you.

Comment: I had nothing to do with the deletion and can't speak to what happened. But it's important to remember that something can be useful and still not appropriate for Stack Overflow. They aren't mutually exclusive. Stack Overflow expects questions to meet a specific set of format requirements, besides just being useful. I don't have the rep level required to see deleted posts so beyond that I can't speak to the quality of the post.

Comment: Now I even lost my motivation to improve a closed question! and you can see this in my new Title for this question. I am not sure my efforts to improve a question worth if they less reevaluate a closed question, it is what I have experienced.

Comment: It is definitely worth it to try to improve a closed question - it absolutely **is possible** to get a closed question reopened if you make enough improvements. But you're even better off just putting in the effort to make sure your questions are high quality *from the start*.

Comment: As an aside, I've posted a separate question (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284938/exactly-how-commonly-closed-questions-are-reopened) asking if there's any way to query the site data and find out exactly how often closed questions are reopened. I suspect it's not nearly as uncommon as you feel it is; we'll see if we can find out the real numbers.

Comment: Thank you but I just don't know why when I mention a point the community give me a negative feedback (down-votes here), but as another person do that it receives attention (up-vote there).

Comment: I felt this goes without saying but... @Ahmad doesn't that simply mean you bring points that the community disagree with? What does this have to do with others' posts?

Comment: @Unihedro I meant when the other one mention the same or similar point! For several times I raised some good points in my questions when other people made a distinct question for them. You may know the examples. one is here and the sphanley related question, also the Bart question related to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284017/how-can-a-currently-banned-user-benefit-from-the-rate-limit-policy-for-questions. Anyway, there is a good point in my question here.

Comment: @Unihedro Moreover I know the community you mention, then biased votes don't mean much to me.

Comment: Nowhere in this question do you ask the percentage of closed questions that are reopened. You need to give your question a good readthrough again and try to honestly consider if it's well written and clearly states a question, because your perception of what you're asking seems to be very different from the rest of us who are reading it.

Comment: And there's a piece of advice that's given again and again to people in your situation: don't try to justify your posts by comparing them to other questions. That's not how they're being judged - people vote on your question based on the quality of your question, plain and simple.

Comment: @sphanley, Really? Really and really the point in the title of this question is SO BAD?  I don't mean I had your question, your question just lead to this important question, is it worth? mine is more important.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "important", but my question is a concise, well stated single question (which, as it happens, was closed, and  I'm not raising a fuss over it) while yours is somewhat long, tries to make several points at once, feels like a rehash of lots of similar posts, and doesn't have a clear question statement. However, as I said, trying to compare the quality of any two questions is a very poor way of measuring anything. This just proves again the very point my answer describes - presentation matters.

Comment: @sphanley those examples you may find redundant, was my try to make my question more clear by providing examples. I also know  and like to write concise questions, but still I am confused with the style of questions here, sometimes you complain that it lacks examples and now you tell its long.

Comment: @Unihedro for another example you can compare the votes for this question and the one which is mentioned as duplicate, however I don't think they are duplicate but if they are they must be receipt in similar way, not one +44 and one -14. I am really confused with these double standards.

Comment: @Ahmad You're mentioning you don't think the questions are duplicates yet you're comparing your posts with theirs as if your post is as excellent and concise as theirs with the same idea being conveyed to fit in the context of "when another person posts the same point they get upvotes"? I am really confused by __your__ double standards.

Comment: Stop comparing your questions to those of others to find some form of justification @Ahmad. Focus on your own and improve. That's the only way forward.

Comment: @Unihedro Lol, thank you, I don't know why I should say my meanings in detail, no insult! I say it's a contradiction, if they are the same then they should be receipt in similar way, and if they are not then it shouldn't be marked as duplicate. However I agree those who counted it duplicate could be different from those who vote it, but beside these arguments the gap is too high to be simply justified. Thank you for editing by the way!

Comment: @Ahmad Look - You just wrote three sentences in the comment above this one, none of which are at all relevant to each other - As waterfall commentary, I never said or implied that you were insulting anyone, if at all; Secondly, "if they are the same then they should be receipt in similar way, and if they are not then it shouldn't be marked as duplicate" -> makes no sense because you're implying these cases and outcomes to be inversely proportional, while "receipting in similar ways" and "marking as duplicate" are not at all contradictory. I don't understand what you're trying to convey here.

Answer (score 7):

Closed questions that actually get edited into quality on topic questions are extraordinarily likely to end up being reopened.  A lot of work has been spent on the reopen workflow in order to make this be the case.

Of course, only a tiny fraction of questions that end up being closed actually get improved into quality on topic questions, so the likelihood of any given closed question getting reopened is very low simply because the likelihood of it ever being improved is so low.  You most likely have seen people expressing this sentiment, and confused it as meaning that questions that are actually improved don't get reopened, which really just isn't the case.

As to whether or not its "worth it".  That's not something anyone else can tell you.  Only you can know if it's worth the effort to get your question reopened.

Comment: Your answer and this comment "All questions receive less attention after a bit of time passes since their asking..." on the Bart answer was close to what I have tried to say in my question, I modified my question to convey my purpose better. You may also want to address those part I asked. Also I hope it be reopend. the other questions is different and mainly about answers not the question...

Comment: @Ahmad Older questions do get less attention than newer ones, but due to the Reopen Queue they still tend to get reopened quite effectively when they are edited to become quality questions.  Your question hasn't been reopened despite quite a *lot* of attention from people with the privilege to reopen because it just doesn't merit reopening.

Answer (score 6):

> If a question can be restated so it turns to a useful question, then I expect the reason for closing it should be reconsidered too.

Absolutely. If you restate a question in such a way that it's good, clear and on-topic, it should be reopened.

However, that evaluation is not up to you. It's up to the community. That you think it's valuable or clear or on-topic doesn't really matter. [Edits will push your questions into a review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/165773) and the community can evaluate to see if it deserves to be reopened.

If that doesn't happen, you have apparently not convinced enough users that your question should be reopened. Or, in the worst case, you have actually edited it into something that should be closed as well. In which case one could argue that there's no real point in reopening it if it has to be closed again anyway.

It it worth improving closed questions? Most definitely. But your mileage may vary depending on how well you did.

Comment: You know Bart, I think you say about what is expected. but I say what has happened and out of my experience, I don't know what is the reason behind it (maybe because moderators are busy). But it seems for some users , closed questions receive less attention. If it's the case then the motivation to improve them decrease for people like me.

Comment: Don't exclude the chance that your question might simply not be up to scratch.

Comment: @Ahmad *All* questions receive less attention after a bit of time passes since their asking.  All old questions have less attention than newer questions.  That said, it's typically not very hard for a question that really is dramatically improved to get *enough* attention to get reopened, due to views caused by activity, and in particular the Reopen review queue.

Comment: And then there still is the case of how you improve your posts. If you need a lot of revisions to gradually improve your question, at revision 20 you've essentially given the community 19 pings of something that was apparently not up to scratch. It doesn't always have to be the case, but it might be something to keep in mind.

Comment: It seems I missed a key point in my question. Actually I didn't ask the questions yesterday, both were closed 3 months ago. the second one which is now reopened was in its current status for a month. anyway I added this information to my question and its not duplicate.

Comment: None of that changes anything I've said.