# Exactly how commonly closed questions are reopened?

Tags: discussion

As a tangent to the active question regarding [whether it's worth improving closed questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284934/should-i-improve-a-closed-question), I began wondering what percentage of closed questions are ever reopened. I have a feeling that it's not as uncommon as the poster in that question feels it is, but is there a way to pull hard numbers on exactly how often people are successful in turning around their closed questions? I searched to see if this had been measured in the past but didn't find anything on this topic historically.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the process through which it can happen. I just wondered if there's a way to query the data to see the actual proportion of closed questions to reopened.

Answer (score 0):

We have to be cautious about what data we seek and how we interpret the data. The issue at stake seems to be this proposition:

> It is pointless to edit a question that has been closed because the question will remain closed **irrespective of whether it has been improved to the point of no longer being close-worthy.**

What if we find that the vast majority of questions remain closed? Would this *prove* the claim? I don't think so.

We'd have to take a sample of questions and look at questions *individually* and decide whether the question *should* have been reopened after it was edited and yet remained closed. *If* the vast majority of closed questions are not edited *in a way that makes them worthy of being reopened* then we would expect that most questions would not be reopened. The problem then would not be that closure is a death sentence but that the authors of the questions are not fixing their questions in such a way that warrants reopening. Many a time I've seen a question that was originally unclear become too broad, or opinion-based.

Comment: What is the strategy or approach of the website? How often do you consider closed questions? or in the other words how much do you (by you I mean those who are responsible for that) try to save some closed questions?